# unfiltered wildcard cts:element-value-query give false results

Tags: marklogic

I got many false search results from cts:element-value-query with **"unfiltered" "whitespace-sensitive" "wildcarded"** option.
I want to know the explanation.
(filtered CTS search seems to be working fine. It seems it works if I remove "whitespace-sensitive")

Here is the target element value I want to find 'ABC/DE 123/FG HI12'

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

(:Case 1:)
let $term1 := 'ABC/DE 123'

(:Case 2:)
let $term2 := 'ABC/DE 123*'

(:Case 3:)
let $term3 := 'ABC/DE 123 *'

(:Case 4:)
let $term4 := 'ABC/DE 123* '

(:Case 5:)
let $term5 := 'ABC/DE 123* *'


let $queries := cts:and-query((cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("","name"), $term2, ("case-insensitive","diacritic-sensitive","punctuation-sensitive","whitespace-sensitive", "wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), cts:collection-query("http://marklogic.com/collections/dls/latest-version")))


return 
xdmp:plan(cts:search(fn:doc(), $queries, 'unfiltered'))
```

Here are the query plan for case 2 and case 3.
My question is why they are different.

[image: case2]

[image: case3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plans are different because you have the wildcard in different places, and with `cts:element-value-query` wildcard matches do not span word boundaries.

- With case 2 `ABC/DE 123*`, the wildcard is for the "word" starting with `123`.
- With case 3 `ABC/DE 123 *`, it will look for `123` and then `*` matches everything after it.

There is a note in the `cts:element-value-query` about wildcards that explains:

> - Note that the text content for the value in a `cts:element-value-query` is treated the same as a phrase in a `cts:word-query`, where the phrase is the element value. Therefore, any wildcard and/or stemming rules are treated like a phrase. For example, if you have an element value of "hello friend" with wildcarding enabled for a query, a `cts:element-value-query` for "he*" will not match because the wildcard matches do not span word boundaries, but a `cts:element-value-query` for "hello *" will match. A search for "*" will match, because a "*" wildcard by itself is defined to match the value. Similarly, stemming rules are applied to each term, so a search for "hello friends" would match when stemming is enabled for the query because "friends" matches "friend".

Also, some of the relevant bullet points from the [Rules for Wildcard Searches](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard#id_61953):

> - Spaces are used as word breaks, and wildcard matching only works within a single word. For example, `m*th*` will match `method` but not `meet there`.
> - If the `*` wildcard is specified with a non-wildcard character, it will match in value lexicon queries (for example, `cts:element-value-match`), but will not match in value queries (for example, `cts:element-value-query`). For example, `m*` will match the value `meet me there` for a value lexicon search (for example, `cts:element-value-match`) but will not match the value for a value query search (for example, `cts:element-value-query`), because the value query only matches the one word. A value search for `m* *` will match the value (because `m*` matches the first word and `*` matches everything after it).
> - If the query has the `whitespace-sensitive` option, then whitespace is treated as word characters. This can be useful for matching spaces in wildcarded value queries.  You can use the `whitespace-sensitive` option in wildcarded word queries, too, although it might not make much sense, as it will match more than you might expect.